# String into integer array without second array

Tags: java, arrays, split, java.util.scanner

I have as an input a String which is a set of numbers with spaces between them, for example:

```
"30 129 48 29 110 90"
```

What I want to do is to take that String and input it in an array as integers without firstly using a second array which will store the numbers as Strings. This is what I know how to do:

```
String line = input.nextLine();
String[] arr = line.split(" ");
int[] array = new int[arr.length];


for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    array[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
}
```

I want to not make 2 arrays to do the job but in some way to have it done at once in the for loop, I just want it like that because it would be better to my eyes and I like writing clean code which I'll be able to easily correct later.

EDIT:After jogabonito's answer this is what I managed to do

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("Input: ");

    StringTokenizer line = new StringTokenizer(input.nextLine());
    int[] numbers = new int[line.countTokens()];


    for (int i = 0; line.hasMoreTokens(); i++){
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt((String)line.nextElement());
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow your line of reasoning. Avoiding the auxiliary array will quite likely result in code that's *less* readable than this.

Comment: It's just that using two arrays to do one simple thing somehow just doesn't sit quite well with me, I want something that will likely convert each number inside the for loop instantly without having to rely on a second array

Comment: Take note that you'll either use an extra array or analyze the string twice: first time just to count the numbers, second time to fill your one array.

Comment: Well you can use `indexOf()` and `substring()` and so on, but such code will look pretty messy. It will be done in one cycle with one array.

Comment: @Gaim And how will OP obtain the count of numbers before starting to fill the `int` array? It's **impossiburu**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current approach is fine, but if you want you "could" do this using [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).
Create an int[] of size determined by `countElements()`, and then in a while -loop doing an `Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextElement())`

Tested code:

```
    String input = "30 129 48 29 110 90";
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input);
    int count = tokenizer.countTokens();
    int x[] = new int[count];
    int i=0;
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        x[i++] = Integer.parseInt((String)tokenizer.nextElement());
    }
```

Comment: +1: I think this is the best match of API with OP's requirement. It will give good-looking code and achieve his goal. It won't avoid scanning the string twice, but that's OP's call.

Comment: I'm implementing this but with a bit of a different aproach because I want to avoid using the while loop because of the declaration of the int i = 0 (yes I am getting paranoid with the code but I'm really close to implement it with the for loop :P ). In the end I don't think it works out with the for loop..

Comment: @SilliconTouch `for (int i=0; tokenizer.hasMoreTokens(); i++) x[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());` And you don't really need `count` as a var, inline it. You could have also written the most straightforward for-loop, checking against `x.length`. There would be nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I believe I managed to implement what you were talking about, check out the edit in my post

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while sc.hasNextInt()
   int i = sc.nextInt();
```

I don't know if it is more readable though, or even if it is better performant. But it sure is another way of doing it. And you cannot know beforehand how many ints would be there, so you'll need to use a list.

Comment: To make this comparable to OP's code, don't forget to also implement the logic that would produce the `int[]` array!

Comment: @aix And that's the catch, of course -- he can't get the count!

Comment: yeah I've tried that, problem is that the String ends with pressing enter and this solution doesn't work with that but I've found an implementation by creating a scanner in the string but in the end I need it to be in an array not a List

Comment: @SilliconTouch: IMO you're overthinking this.

Comment: @aix Sometimes it's good to overthink -- as a learning process.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you WANT to use an array instead of a [Collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework)?

I think something along the following lines

```
String input = "30 129 48 29 110 90";
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (String token: input.split(" ")) {
    list.add( Integer.valueOf( token ) );
}
```

You could of course convert the list to an array:

```
Integer[] array = list.toArray( new Integer[] {} );
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just want it like that because it would be better to my eyes and I like writing clean code which I'll be able to easily correct later.

In that case, don't change a thing. What you have is probably as readable as it can be.